# Heroku toolbelt doesn't seem to be using HTTP over SSH

Tags: git, heroku

I've installed the latest heroku toolbelt (3.38.2) and am trying to deploy to my heroku instance. I know that SSH is blocked by my company firewall however I understand that the heroku toolbelt now uses HTTP by default.

I ran the following commands

```html
git init
$ heroku git:remote -a myheroku
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "commit"
$ git push heroku master
```

However I still get the error:
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

And this suggests it is trying to do the push via SSH.

I also tried running the command
heroku git:remote -http-git
to try to force it but the result is the same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the remote url in your .git/config

Comment: Looks like I still have some Firewall blocking problems to solve so that may be related.